# Pear site moved to new host, some pages not working

Tags: php, pear

I have an old shared hosting plan and I am moving the site to a new VPS hosting plan. It was coded in PHP.

The site moved successfully, but when I try to access a page I get this error:

```
    Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_DataObject_Error::getDatabaseConnection() in /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/ss/index.php on line 11
```

Ring any bells as to why this is happening? I am not familiar with pear, so figured id post this here before I spend many hours trying to figure this one out.

edit: And if I uncomment out those lines, the rest of the page seems to work (cant test most of it ATM tho)... I wonder if this can be a deprecated method?

Comment: Can you add which hosting plans you switched between?

Comment: its from an old web.com hosting package, I highly recommend you not use it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was my database.INI file that DataObject loads did not know what DB to use (it was set wrong). So any place in the code depending on an instance of the DataObject would fail. Here is code that can give you a better error message (as opposed to calling a method that does not exist and getting a php error):

```
$userobject = DB_DataObject::factory($tablename);
if (PEAR::isError($userobject)) 
{
   echo $userobject->message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well PEAR is just a program to easily install PHP modules from their repository, so you will need to make sure that you have or install PEAR on your new server. Then use PEAR to install the missing module: **DB_DataObject**

https://pear.php.net/package/DB_DataObject/redirected

Once you get that installed, you may find you need additional packages and modules for PHP since the code will stop when it reaches a Fatal Error. You may have more Fatal Errors after line 11.

When moving to a new provider for PHP, you always want to make sure you have a list of modules, configurations, and third party programs (like MySQL or Redis) so you can ensure that the new provider meets your requirements (or gives you access to install what you need).

Comment: PEAR is installed along with the DB_DataObject module. When I run the command "pear list' it also list that package. This is the line that breaks: 
$do = DB_DataObject::factory('ssparticipant');
$db = $do->getDatabaseConnection(); .... I am starting to think its just not able to connect to the table (because when I put in a fake db username, it gives me a DB error)

Comment: Yeah, without more information it is going to be hard to help. Can you post up some of the code? Are you able to manually connect to the database and query the table your code is with the exact same query that is throwing this error? If it is a permissions issue, sometimes they don't return the correct error or any at all.

Comment: The two lines of code causing the issue are:  $do = DB_DataObject::factory('ssparticipant'); $db = $do->getDatabaseConnection();